# Correct way to start a command line exe (ngrok) from code behind

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, ngrok

Im tryng to sart ngrok from a WPF C# app.

The desired result would be windows command line opening and ngrok starting up as if I had manually started it.

Im getting an exception: System.InvalidOperationException

```
private async void StartNgrok()
    {
        string ExePath = "C:\\Users\\mmcca\\ngrok.exe";
        string Args = "\"http 55678 -host-header=\"localhost: 55678\"";

        try
        {
            var proc = Process.Start(ExePath, Args);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Throwing - System.InvalidOperationexception
        }
```

What is the correct way to start a command line exe from code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You could try declaring ngrok as a Process, and then starting it this way - this has worked for me in the past:

```
Process ngrok = new Process();
ngrok.StartInfo.FileName   = "C:\\Users\\mmcca\\ngrok.exe";
ngrok.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"http 55678 -host-header=\"localhost: 55678\"";
ngrok.Start();
```

Let me know how you get on with this.